# Sonata Admin on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

First, I'm sorry for my bad english.

I developp a little project on Symfony. I use Sonata Admin for my panel administration.

I want to custom left menu. In fact, by default, items are grouped. 
How to do for single items ?

My code :

```
# services.yml
admin.page:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\PageAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\PageEntity, ~]
    tags: - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Page,label: Page }
    public: true
```

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: please add the actual code and not an image (fyi image is broken anyway).

Comment: on Sonata admin there are a bunch of twig templates which you can override partially. In this case you can override the "admin list block" in the Dashboard template: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/dashboard.html#the-admin-list-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[2.6. Show menu item without treeview](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu.html)

Add to your admin service tag `on_top: true`

```
 tags:
    - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Post, on_top: true}
```